# date convert while xml value read

Tags: java, date, jaxb

I have xml in which two field are Date like below

```
<CreateDate1>2019-03-07T09:42:20.65737Z</CreateDate1>
<CreateDate2>2019-03-07T00:00:00</CreateDate2>
```

when I am specifying type String in Pojo for these two, I am able to get the same values as in xml in String format.

But My requirement is to get these two field in Date format.

So I tried specifying Date type in Pojo for these two but i am getting some different format result for these two.

output :

```
CreateDate1= Thu Mar 07 15:12:20 IST 2019, CreateDate2= Thu Mar 07 00:00:00 IST 2019
```

expected output in Date format: `CreateDate1= 2019-03-07T09:42:20.65737Z, CreateDate2= 2019-03-07T00:00:00`

```
private Date CreateDate1;
private Date CreateDate2;
private Department department;
 
public Date getCreateDate1() {
    return CreateDate1;
}
 
public Date getCreateDate2() {
    return CreateDate2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Sample [CreateDate1= " + CreateDate1 + ", CreateDate2= " + CreateDate2 + "]";
}
```

Can someone please hepp me on this .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `CreateDate1` always have the trailing `Z` (for UTC)  and `CreateDate2` never?

Comment: yes CreateDate2 does not has Z in last. @Ole V.V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ZonedDateTime` for `createDate1` (because you need time-zone information in it) and `LocalDateTime` for `createDate2` (because you do not need time-zone or offset information in it).

Given below is how you should parse the date-time string and how you should create a `String` to be returned from the `toString()` method:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Parse the date-time string from your XML as follows. You can do it in
        // the constructor(s) or setters

        // --------------------------------For createDate1-----------------------------
        String dateTimeStr1 = "2019-03-07T09:42:20.65737Z";
        ZonedDateTime createDate1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr1);
        System.out.println(createDate1);

        // --------------------------------For createDate2-----------------------------
        // Define format for parsing
        DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d'T'H.m.s");            
        String dateTimeStr2 = "2019-03-07T00.00.00";
        LocalDateTime createDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, parseFormat);

        // -----Create a string to be returned from the `toString()` method as follows------
        // Define format for printing
        DateTimeFormatter printFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH.mm.ss");
        String toString = "Sample [CreateDate1= " + createDate1.toString() + ", CreateDate2= "
                + createDate2.format(printFormat) + "]";

        System.out.println(toString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-03-07T09:42:20.657370Z
Sample [CreateDate1= 2019-03-07T09:42:20.657370Z, CreateDate2= 2019-03-07T00.00.00]
```

Comment: `createDate2` should be `LocalDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime`. --- The value is not derived from `createDate1` like your code shows.

Comment: @Arvind Thanks for the help, for CreateDate1 I am able to get my result, but for CreateDate2 my xml input date is "2019-03-07T00.00.00" not "2019-03-07T09:42:20.65737Z". I am getting parsing execption if I am using String dateTimeStr ="2019-03-07T00.00.00" for CreateDate2. at this line  ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr).toLocalDateTime().

Comment: @rakesh - I've updated the answer as per your requirement. I hope it fulfils your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @Arvind i tried just now, your answer works actullay if i create String dateTimeStr2 = "2019-03-07T00.00.00"; ans pass to LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, format); but in my case String CreateDate2 is coming from xml when I am printing it on screen its simply print the "2019-03-07T00.00.00" but when I am passing it to LocalDateTime.parse(CreateDate2, format); I am getting parseexception. also I want this createDate2 in Some Date Object not in String 
 java.time.format.dateTimeParseException: Test '2019-03-07T00.00.0' could not parse at index 17

Comment: @rakesh - You got the error because you had just 0 instead of 00 for the second part in the date-time string. However, such a thing can be solved by using a single letter for each part (second, minute, hour etc.) of the date-time string. I've updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if you face any other issue. I could not understand your comment, `also I want this createDate2 in Some Date Object not in String` - as `LocalDateTime createDate2` is a `LocalDate` object, not a `String` object.

Comment: @Arvind that is the silliest mistake i did, input xml createDate2 had only `0` not `00`. Just one last part I need createDate2 in some Date object like Date like for createDate1 its reurning ZonedDateTime but for createDate2 its String type while return.

Comment: @rakesh - I've already mentioned in my last comment that `createDate2` is a `LocalDate` instance, not a `String` instance. Where is the confusion?

Comment: @Arvind (If I wanted createDate2  in string I could directly get the string xml 
 input for createDate2 and print it but i need it in some Date type of java while returning from get method and also in toString( method) )

Comment: You've to write `DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d'T'H.m.s"); String dateTimeStr2 = "2019-03-07T00.00.00"; LocalDateTime createDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, parseFormat); return createDate2;` in the get method. I'm not able to understand what problem you are facing.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes createDate2 is a LocalDate instance but  createDate2.format(printFormat) retrun String not LocalDate

Comment: `createDate2.format(printFormat)` is required as `String` itself because the `toString` method returns a `String`, not any date type object.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I would accept it, but still for createDate2  I am need to return some Date type, I also tried `DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d'T'H.m.s"); String dateTimeStr2 = "2019-03-07T00.00.00"; LocalDateTime createDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, parseFormat); return createDate2;` with this code i am able to return LocalDateTime instance but it removes `.00` it only return  `2019-03-07T00.00`

Comment: An object of `LocalDateTime` (or any type representing date-time) is an object which has date-time information (e.g. year, month, day, hour, minute etc.) and if you print a `LocalDateTime` object, it will always invoke its `toString` method. That is why you have `DateTimeFormatter` class so that you can print it in your desired formats.

Answer (score 1):

The `<CreateDate1>` value `2019-03-07T09:42:20.65737Z` has a time zone offset (the `Z` at the end), specifying a `+00:00` offset, i.e. the `UTC` offset. As such, it parses to `Date` exactly and displays by default in the JVM's default time zone, which is `IST` in your example, and explains the `+05:00` offset in the displayed time-of-day.

The `<CreateDate2>` value `2019-03-07T00:00:00` does not have a time zone offset, so it is parsed in the JVM's default time zone, and displays in the default time zone, which explains why the time-of-day is same as input. The actual `Date` value varies, depending on the JVM's default time zone.

If you running with Java 8 or later, you should not use [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for this, since the result varies.

Instead, use [**`Instant`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)) for `CreateDate1`. `Instant` requires the input to use `Z` as time zone offset. The other two can handle other offsets.

Use [**`LocalDateTime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for `CreateDate2`, since that correctly represents a date/time value without a time zone.

If you make these changes, the output will be:

```java
Sample [CreateDate1= 2019-03-07T09:42:20.657370Z, CreateDate2= 2019-03-07T00:00]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, for CreateDate1 I am able to get my result but for CreateDate2 it removes last two 00 CreateDate2= 2019-03-07T00:00

Comment: @rakesh That is just the default format, you can specify your own format if you want the seconds to be displayed even when zero.

Comment: @Andres for createDate2 i need retrun as some Date type not string, I tried this code  `DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d'T'H.m.s"); 
String dateTimeStr2 = "2019-03-07T00.00.00"; 
LocalDateTime createDate2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr2, parseFormat); here createDate2 retrun LocalDateTime instance but it removes .00 it only return 2019-03-07T00.00

if i add this `String formattedDate=createDate2.format(parseFormat);`  it works but return String type. i need it in Date type
`

Comment: @rakesh `LocalDateTime` *is* a "Date type". If you return a `LocalDateTime` then you are returning a date/time value with precision to the *nano-second*. You are **not** returning a string with `2019-03-07T00.00`. That string value is generated later when you call `toString()` implicitly, e.g. when printing it. --- If the parsed value was `2019-03-07T09:42:20`, then that is what will print later. The default format simply doesn't show the second value if it is zero, same as it doesn't show fractional seconds when they are zero.